# How to get media from external source in hybris?

Tags: aem, sap-commerce-cloud, dam

How to integrate AEM DAM and Hybris. 
In multimedia tab of products i need to browse to DAM system. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need are the following two keywords:

- MediaURLStrategy
- MediaStorageStrategy

The MediaUrlStrategy resolves a URL to a Media item. The MediaStorageStrategy handles media creation, change and deletion of media items within the hybris media server. Both are interfaces you need to implement.

Next you need a bean definition for your each of your implementations.

For the next step you need to know which folders you want to use the URL/Storage strategies for. Every media has a specific folder. You can assign a URL/Storage strategy for specific folders and you can assign a default strategy. You reference the strategy by its bean id.

This is how you declare the default strategy

```
media.default.storage.strategy=localFileMediaStorageStrategy
media.default.url.strategy=localMediaWebURLStrategy
```

This is how you declare a strategy for the folder abc:

```
media.folder.abc.storage.strategy=myStorageStrategy
media.folder.abc.url.strategy=myUrlStrategy
```

Its very important to know, that hybris uses medias for a lot of internal purposes, e.g. cronjob logs, sync logs, cockpit configuration. So using a publicly accessible store for ALL folders is not recommended.

Make that the following property has a value (e.g. cache):

```
media.default.local.cache.rootCacheFolder=cache
```

In older versions of hybris, when this property had no value, in regular intervals, local medias were deleted.

Comment: user try to ask browse external image library. May be after selectting image from external library, user want to save it to hybris.

Comment: once the images from DAM are all imported in hybris, you can very well browse them in hybris.

Comment: Hi Johannes, thank you for your response. But i need to do this through AEM DAM url which is to be used instead of media model populating when i'm clicking on browse button in multimedia tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom editor and fill it data in backend from DAM. Also you need to customize view of product type in backoffice.xml for your custom editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom renderers for reference. Please check the `pcmbackoffice-config.xml`
In the product's list view and grid view, you would find some renderers. You need to override the preview renderer.